# Access variables across applications hosted on IIS

Tags: .net, iis

I have a website hosted on IIS, consisting of two applications, using the same application pool and having the same physical path.
The only difference is one allows anonymous, the other window authentication only. (as you cannot have both enabled at the same time)

Is it now possible to access variables or objects across these two applications?

I have a list of connected users which should be indepdendent of which application was used to authenticate. Right now this list would be different for both applications.

I read about cross domain singletons, which seems to be what I need? But I cannot get it to work sadly.

Comment: You can try to use VBScript and Application.Contents Collection to get the Application Object, more information about [Application Object (IIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525360(v=vs.90)) you can refer this link.

Comment: I have done some reading and testing on this but it doesn't seem to work here :(

Comment: How did you test it and is there any error message?

Comment: I'm using .NET Core and from what I read this is not available there. Also I cannot access the Application object in my code. It doesn't exist.

Comment: if you want to get Application object from .net core application, you first need to register the cache at startup, and then inject it.